# What does "Wouldn’t have said it was" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ‘Where’s the bloke who kept on about being here illegally?’
>
> The Doctor stood up and moved forward. ‘Yes?’ he said curtly.
>
> ‘What do you want?’
>
> He could just make out Thermus raising his eyebrows. ‘There now, is
>   that any way to talk to someone who’s come to let you out?’
>
> ‘**Wouldn’t have said it was**, Thermus,’ said Flaccus, standing beside
>   him, holding the dungeon key. ‘I’d have said that was more the way of
>   an ungrateful wretch who doesn’t appreciate all we’ve been doing for
>   him.’

[The Stone Rose](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9187065/8/The-Stone-Rose)
It wouldn't? I wouldn't?
Flaccus hadn't say anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Wouldn't have said it was' is a reply to the question that Thermus asked.

It means 'I would not consider the manner in which the Doctor has just spoken to Thermus to be appropriate.'

Wouldn't is a contracted form of would not, and the 'it' in question is the manner in which the Doctor spoke.